# how to write this query using DATE_FORMAT using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

Basically, I want a news page with Archives list in the side column based on the month and year.. for example June 2012. The table is named 'news', with columns news_id, news_title, news_entry, updated, created. Updated and created are timestamps. Right now I am using normal php  as below:

```
mysql_select_db($database_admin_conn, $admin_conn);
$query_getArchives = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (news.updated, '%M %Y') AS archive, DATE_FORMAT (news.updated, '%Y-%m') AS link FROM news ORDER BY news.updated DESC";
$getArchives = mysql_query($query_getArchives, $admin_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getArchives = mysql_fetch_assoc($getArchives);
$totalRows_getArchives = mysql_num_rows($getArchives);
```

Code to display archives column is as below:

```
<h3>News Archives</h3>
<ul>
<?php do { ?>
<li class="seperator
<?php echo (isset($_GET['archive']) && $_GET['archive'] == $row_getArchives['link'] ? 'currentItem' : '') ?>">
<a href="news.php?archive=<?php echo $row_getArchives['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row_getArchives['archive']; ?></a>
</li>
<?php } while ($row_getArchives = mysql_fetch_assoc($getArchives)); ?>
</ul>
```

How do I realise the select statement in the first block of code in Zend Framework, to achieve the same result as the present code output? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First create table class into */models/DbTable/Archive.php* or using zf command tool.

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_Archive extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'news'; // actual table name here
}
```

Then use the following code

```
$table = new Application_Model_DbTable_Archive();

$select = $table->getAdapter()->select()
            ->from(array('news' => $table->info(Zend_Db_Table::NAME)), 
                array(
                    'archive'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (news.updated, \'%M %Y\')'), 
                    'link'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (news.updated, \'%Y-%m\')')))
            ->order('news.updated DESC');
// then use $select
$row_getArchives = $table->fetchAll($select);
$totalRows_getArchives  = $row_getArchives ->count();
```

and the view

```
foreach($row_getArchives as $row){
    echo $row->link;
}
```

---

If you don`t want to use table classes, try this one:

```
$adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $adapter->select()
        ->from(array('news' => 'news'), 
            array(
                'archive'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (news.updated, \'%M %Y\')'), 
                'link'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (news.updated, \'%Y-%m\')')))
        ->order('news.updated DESC');
// then use $select
$row_getArchives = $adapter->fetchAll($select);
$totalRows_getArchives  = count($row_getArchives);
```

and the view

```
foreach($row_getArchives as $row){
    echo $row['link'];
}
```

Comment: @TimFountain I just love to use db-classes, since they keep table name and I don`t need to remember it, I just use `$table->info(Zend_Db_Table::NAME)` In case I wish to change table name, I have to change it just in the class. It`s convenient.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but that is leavin me with this error: Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Archive' not found in C:\vhosts\balaji\news\news.php on line 15. Reading the Zend help documentation now :)

Comment: @atomheart you should first create zf project and then create table class. Try the updated answer and accept it if works =)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ivan. For this particular project, I am only using Zend for connecting to the database using using library/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php, and reading and writing into database. For my next learning project, I intend to get more involved with Zend. For my present requirement, I wanted to know if the select statement can be realised in a zend select statement format. something like: $getRecent = $dbRead->select('news_id', 'news_title')->FROM('news')->ORDER(updated);

Comment: @atomheart If you don`t want to create table class, use the updated answer.

Comment: Hello Ivan, thanks again. But It comes up with an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object  ..

Comment: @atomheart Ok, your problem is adapter initialization rather than just query. You should fix your question. Good luck.